# How to get native call stack from managed code?

Tags: windbg

I am trying to debug a managed Win32 app on 64 bit Windows 8.1 Pro. I loaded SOS `.cordll -ve -u -l` and `.loadby SOS clr` and set the symbol path to Microsoft's public server.

I can get the CLR call stack but when I try to get the managed call stack (`K 10`), I get just the following. Wondering what I am missing.

```
00f8c23c 6c11777c PresentationCore_ni+0x1b76f0
00f8c2a8 6c114c57 PresentationCore_ni+0x1b777c
00f8c32c 6c1148af PresentationCore_ni+0x1b4c57
00f8c384 6c113926 PresentationCore_ni+0x1b48af
00f8c41c 6c1132e7 PresentationCore_ni+0x1b3926
00f8c440 6c11324f PresentationCore_ni+0x1b32e7
00f8c464 6b0b65da PresentationCore_ni+0x1b324f
00f8c4a0 6b0b6426 PresentationFramework_ni+0x3465da
00f8c52c 6b0b5ec6 PresentationFramework_ni+0x346426
00f8c57c 6b049bfc PresentationFramework_ni+0x345ec6
00f8c778 6c10e0ec PresentationFramework_ni+0x2d9bfc
00f8c7f4 6b054f45 PresentationCore_ni+0x1ae0ec
00f8c814 6b05a211 PresentationFramework_ni+0x2e4f45
00f8c870 6b049bfc PresentationFramework_ni+0x2ea211
00f8ca6c 6c10e0ec PresentationFramework_ni+0x2d9bfc
```

Comment: SOS comes with a help file. Do `!sos.help` to get started.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you mixed up native call stack and managed (CLR) call stack.

- `k` gives you the native call stack.
- `!clrstack` (SOS) gives you the managed call stack.
- `!dumpstack` (SOS) gives you both.
- `!mk` of [SOSEX](http://www.stevestechspot.com/) also gives you both, but in a nicer way.

Comment: I was using windbg 6. I got the call stack after switching to latest windbg 10. It's still in preview.

Thanks Thomas. SOS commands helped to get the managed call stack.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/yongrhee/archive/2015/04/05/debugging-tools-for-windows-windbg-adplus-v10-0-10041-3.aspx

Comment: Which WinDbg 6? Almost every version is 6: See http://debugging.wellisolutions.de/windbg-versions/

Comment: I downloaded windbg 6 for windows 8.1 from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852365.aspx